# The class of spaces where every Borel measure is atomic

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

I have been considering the following question:

Let $X$ be a compact, metrizable space with the following property: every (regular) Borel probability measure on $X$ is atomic, i.e. for each $\mu\in\text{Prob}(X)$ there exists $x_\mu\in X$ such that $\mu(\{x_\mu\})>0$. Does it follow that $X$ is countable?

It is trivial to see that countable spaces satisfy this property, due to the fact that measures are countably additive. From the discussion in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182794/every-uncountable-compact-uniform-space-has-a-nonatomic-measure?fbclid=IwAR3IEwV0SvqUY4uNDBlZPCDBRFp7iJqiG400YOf31irdLqWNkAjHCkp6tnc), it seems that $\omega_1+1$ does indeed have the above property. However, $\omega_1+1$ is not metrizable. I would like to know if there are counter-examples coming from metrizable spaces and, in the case that such examples exist, I would also be interested in the same question if we restrict our attention to zero dimensional compact metrizable spaces (i.e. having a basis consisting of clopen sets).

Any comments or references are appreciated. Also, since I'm new here it could be that this is too elementary for an MO post. If that's the case I will migrate this question to MSE.

Comment: Of course there are metrizable non-compact spaces where every Borel measure is atomic.  For example, the discrete space of power $\aleph_1$, due to Ulam.

Comment: It seem that this class coincides with the class of scattered space (even in the class of compact Hausdorff spaces).

Comment: @Taras: You are right; this was proved by Walter Rudin (PAMS 1957) and A. Pelczynski / Z. Semadeni (Studia Math. 1959).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Every uncountable Polish space is isomorphic as a measurable space to the unit interval by Kuratowski's isomorphism theorem and admits, therefore, a nonatomic probability measure. On a Polish space, every finite Borel measure is regular.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of Kuratowski's theorem.

Comment: Or you can use the elementary topological fact that every uncountable compact metric space contains a subset that is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: @BillJohnson Thank you, I did not know this as well. I was only aware of the fact that compact metric spaces are quotients of the Cantor set.